# Making testfunc that allows 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3

Tags: python, testing, floating-point, integer

I've just started my first programming course (in a while), and I'm working on the following task:

We are asked to make a function add(x,y) that adds the two arguments. We then implement this function in a testfunction, test_add(), and use an assert statement to make sure the add-function is working correctly. As long as the arguments are integers, all is fine. Then, we are asked to implement a test in our add-function to make sure that 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3. I've read up on the topic, and know that their representation will be approximated using binary fraction, such that what I'm actually adding is 0.100000000000000005551115123126 + 0.2200000000000000011102230246252 = 0.30000000000000004 and therefore, my testfunction test_add() doesn't pass the pytest. One of the things I've tried is

```
def add(x,y, tol=1e-9):
    if abs(int(x) - x) <= tol:
        x == int(x)
    if abs(int(y) - y) <= tol:
        y == int(y)
 

    return x + y
```

I've also tried

```
def add(x,y, tol=1e-9):
   if isinstance(x, float):
        x == round(x, 1)
   if isinstance(y, float):
        y == round(y, 1)
   return x + y
```

Still no luck though... any hints on how I can implement this test to pass?
Thanks in advance for all help and tips!! :)

Comment: Arent you using conditional operators than using equal?

Comment: Can you share the test code?

Comment: I think you want to specify the tolerance on `test_add()`, not `add()`.

Comment: `assert(abs(add(.1, .2) - .3) <= 1e-9)`

Comment: Show the actual text of the assignment. Getting the problem criteria right is important.

Answer (score 3):

You want to round the result of the addition, not the inputs to the method. i.e.

```
>>> round(.1, 1) + round(.2, 1) == .3
False
>>> round(.1 + .2, 1) == .3
True
```

So your add method could look like this:

```
def add(x, y):
   return round(x + y, 1)
```

```
>>> add(.1, .2) == .3
True
```

If you still want to keep the tolerance of the rounding, change the `tol` parameter to be the number of decimal places to keep:

```
def add(x, y, tol=9):
    return round(x + y, tol)
```

```
>>> add(.1, .2) == .3
True
```

On the other hand, usually when testing a float parameter, it's better to check the bounds and not the value exactly. You can do something like this.

```
>>> tol = 1e-9
>>> expected = .3
>>> actual = .1 + .2
>>> expected - tol <= actual <= expected + tol
True
```

Or more succinctly:

```
>>> abs(expected - actual) <= tol
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python3.5+ you have access to [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality) for these types of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to calculate floating values in your function, it might be beneficial to use [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instead for this purpose.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def add_decimal(x, y):
    return Decimal(str(x)) + Decimal(str(y))

def add_float(x, y):
    return x + y

a = 0.1
b = 0.2
print("Decimal calculation:", add_decimal(a, b))
print("Float calculation:", add_float(a, b))
```

Output

```
Decimal calculation: 0.3
Float calculation: 0.30000000000000004
```